# Reading bytes from a JavaScript string

Tags: javascript

I have a string containing binary data in JavaScript. Now I want to read, for example, an integer from it. So I get the first 4 characters, use `charCodeAt`, do some shifting, etc. to get an integer.

The problem is that strings in JavaScript are UTF-16 (instead of ASCII) and `charCodeAt` often returns values higher than 256.

The [Mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) states that "The first 128 Unicode code points are a direct match of the ASCII character encoding." (what about ASCII values > 128?).

How can I convert the result of `charCodeAt` to an ASCII value? Or is there a better way to convert a string of four characters to a 4 byte integer?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: ASCII has *NO* values > 128 (actually, it has no values > 127: it defines codes between 0 and 127 included, ONLY). So asking about "ASCII values > 128" makes no sense; you must mean some other character encoding (ISO-8859-x for some value of x, maybe?)

Comment: There are extended ASCII codes (from 128 to 255) http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: "Extended ASCII" is not a real thing. "asciitable.com" is actually showing you ISO-8859-1, which has very little to do with how JavaScript stores Unicode strings.

Answer (score 40):

I believe that you can can do this with relatively simple bit operations:

```
function stringToBytes ( str ) {
  var ch, st, re = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++ ) {
    ch = str.charCodeAt(i);  // get char 
    st = [];                 // set up "stack"
    do {
      st.push( ch & 0xFF );  // push byte to stack
      ch = ch >> 8;          // shift value down by 1 byte
    }  
    while ( ch );
    // add stack contents to result
    // done because chars have "wrong" endianness
    re = re.concat( st.reverse() );
  }
  // return an array of bytes
  return re;
}

stringToBytes( "A\u1242B\u4123C" );  // [65, 18, 66, 66, 65, 35, 67]
```

It should be a simple matter to sum the output up by reading the byte array as if it were memory and adding it up into larger numbers:

```
function getIntAt ( arr, offs ) {
  return (arr[offs+0] << 24) +
         (arr[offs+1] << 16) +
         (arr[offs+2] << 8) +
          arr[offs+3];
}

function getWordAt ( arr, offs ) {
  return (arr[offs+0] << 8) +
          arr[offs+1];
}

'\\u' + getWordAt( stringToBytes( "A\u1242" ), 1 ).toString(16);  // "1242"
```

Comment: The encoding you're outputting is not even well-defined. You won't be able to make a round-trip between this fictitious encoding and a string in most cases.

Comment: Indeed.  It's only useful if you KNOW that it's a 2 byte word at index 1.  And you definitely can't know that from your output bytes array.

Answer (score 17):

Borgar's answer seems correct.

Just wanted to clarify one point.  Javascript treats bitwise operations as '32-bit signed int's, where the last (left-most) bit is the sign bit.  Ie,

```
getIntAt([0x7f,0,0,0],0).toString(16)  //  "7f000000"

getIntAt([0x80,0,0,0],0).toString(16)  // "-80000000"
```

However, for octet-data processing (eg, network stream, etc), usually want the 'unsigned int' representation.  This can be accomplished by adding a '>>> 0' (zero-fill right-shift) operator which internally tells Javascript to treat this as unsigned.

```
function getUIntAt ( arr, offs ) {
  return (arr[offs+0] << 24) +
         (arr[offs+1] << 16) +
         (arr[offs+2] << 8) +
          arr[offs+3] >>> 0;
}

getUIntAt([0x80,0,0,0],0).toString(16)   // "80000000"
```

Comment: Instead of relying on a weird trick (>>> 0), we ca replace the problematic << 24, by * Math.pow(2, 24). Instead of being treated as a 32bit unsigned int, this will be considered as a 64bit double. This might be a tiny bit slower though.

return (b3 * Math.pow(2, 24)) + (b2 << 16) + (b1 << 8) + b0;

Thanks for the solution, I patched jDataView thanks to that :) https://github.com/vjeux/jsDataView/commit/2ee4906e8d3fcc954a263c7b161cf3dbf2d4804f

Answer (score 16):

There are two methods for encoding and decoding utf-8 string to a byte array and back.

```
var utf8 = {}

utf8.toByteArray = function(str) {
    var byteArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
        if (str.charCodeAt(i) <= 0x7F)
            byteArray.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
        else {
            var h = encodeURIComponent(str.charAt(i)).substr(1).split('%');
            for (var j = 0; j < h.length; j++)
                byteArray.push(parseInt(h[j], 16));
        }
    return byteArray;
};

utf8.parse = function(byteArray) {
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++)
        str +=  byteArray[i] <= 0x7F?
                byteArray[i] === 0x25 ? "%25" : // %
                String.fromCharCode(byteArray[i]) :
                "%" + byteArray[i].toString(16).toUpperCase();
    return decodeURIComponent(str);
};

// sample
var str = "Да!";
var ba = utf8.toByteArray(str);
alert(ba);             // 208, 148, 208, 176, 33
alert(ba.length);      // 5
alert(utf8.parse(ba)); // Да!
```

Comment: I like this solution. I voted for it.
I don't understand why didn't you include `127` and chose the hexadecimal `0x7F`. I'm using this to detect a multibyte string in JavaScript. eg. `"Şerban".length != toByteArray("Şerban").length`

Answer (score 13):

While [@Borgar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240408/reading-bytes-from-a-javascript-string/8639991#answer-1242596) answers the question correctly, his solution is pretty slow. It took me a while to track it down (I used his function somewhere in a larger project), so I thought I would share my insight.

I ended up having something like [@Kadm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240408/reading-bytes-from-a-javascript-string/8639991#answer-4528265). It's not some little percent faster, it's like 500 times faster (no exaggeration!). I wrote a [little benchmark](http://langweiligeszeug.tumblr.com/post/14830476496/stringtobytes-javascript-performance), so you can see it for yourself :)

```
function stringToBytesFaster ( str ) { 
var ch, st, re = [], j=0;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++ ) { 
    ch = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if(ch < 127)
    {
        re[j++] = ch & 0xFF;
    }
    else
    {
        st = [];    // clear stack
        do {
            st.push( ch & 0xFF );  // push byte to stack
            ch = ch >> 8;          // shift value down by 1 byte
        }
        while ( ch );
        // add stack contents to result
        // done because chars have "wrong" endianness
        st = st.reverse();
        for(var k=0;k<st.length; ++k)
            re[j++] = st[k];
    }
}   
// return an array of bytes
return re; 
}
```

Comment: There seem to be some issues with this for Chinese characters. Codepoint is not the same as the encoding.

Comment: Borgar and Kadm have supplied different solutions that provide different results.  This (really much faster) version of Borgar's code, returns the same result as Borgar's code.  It does not return the same result as Kadm's code, and the author never claimed it did.   The Borgar method extracts raw bytes (in the same fashion as a hex editor, or xxd would do). It has no knowledge of "code points" or unicode.  The Kadm method deconstructs them using encodeUriComponent which **is** unicode aware, and the output is different as a result — although I couldn't explain explain the actual difference.

Comment: so which solution is correct?

Answer (score 6):

Borga's solution works perfectly. In case you want a more concrete implementation, you may want to have a look at the [BinaryReader class from vjeux](http://blog.vjeux.com/2010/javascript/javascript-binary-reader.html) (which, for the records, is based on the [binary-parser class from Jonas Raoni Soares Silva](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/binary-parser)).

Comment: Thank you for those links, very very useful

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume for a second that your objective is to read arbitrary bytes from a string.
My first suggestion would be to make your string representation a hexidecmal representation of the binary data.

You can read the values using conversions to numbers from hex:

```
var BITS_PER_BYTE = 8;

function readBytes(hexString, numBytes) {
    return Number( parseInt( hexString.substr(0, numBytes * (BITS_PER_BYTE/4) ),16 ) );
}

function removeBytes(hexString, numBytes) {
    return hexString.substr( numBytes * (BITS_PER_BYTE/BITS_PER_CHAR) );
}
```

The functions can then be used to read whatever you want:

```
var hex = '4ef2c3382fd';
alert( 'We had: ' + hex );

var intVal = readBytes(hex,2);
alert( 'Two bytes: ' + intVal.toString(2) );

hex = removeBytes(hex,2);
alert( 'Now we have: ' + hex );
```

You can then interpret the byte string however you want.

Hope this helps!
Cheers!

Comment: Just miss `BITS_PER_CHAR` ;)

Answer (score 4):

How did you get the binary data into the string in the first place? How the binary data gets encoded into a string is an IMPORTANT consideration, and you need an answer to that question before you can proceed.

One way I know of to get binary data into a string, is to use the XHR object, and set it to expect UTF-16.

Once it's in utf-16, you can retrieve 16-bit numbers from the string using `"....".charCodeAt(0)`

which will be a number between 0 and 65535

Then, if you like, you can convert that number into two numbers between 0 and 255 like this:

```
var leftByte = mynumber>>>8;
var rightByte = mynumber&255;
```

Answer (score 4):

borgars solution **improvement**:

```
...
do {
      st.unshift( ch & 0xFF );  // push byte to stack
      ch = ch >> 8;          // shift value down by 1 byte
    }  
    while ( ch );
    // add stack contents to result
    // done because chars have "wrong" endianness
    re = re.concat( st );
...
```

Comment: important thing is that this runs much faster then push & reverse

Comment: edit note: depends on size of the array, slows down with larger arrays after some limit there is no difference at all

Answer (score 4):

One nice and quick hack is to use a combination of encodeURI and unescape :

```
t=[]; 
for(s=unescape(encodeURI("zażółć gęślą jaźń")),i=0;i<s.length;++i)
  t.push(s.charCodeAt(i));
t

[122, 97, 197, 188, 195, 179, 197, 130, 196, 135, 32, 103, 196, 153, 197, 155, 108, 196, 133, 32, 106, 97, 197, 186, 197, 132]
```

Perhaps some explanation is necessary why the heck it works, so let me split it into steps:

```
 encodeURI("zażółć gęślą jaźń")
```

returns

```
 "za%C5%BC%C3%B3%C5%82%C4%87%20g%C4%99%C5%9Bl%C4%85%20ja%C5%BA%C5%84"
```

which -- if you look closely -- is the original string in which all characters with values>127 got replaced with (possibly more than one) hexadecimal bytes representations.
For example letter "ż" became "%C5%BC". The fact is encodeURI escapes also some regular ascii characters like spaces, but it does not matter. What matters is that at this point each byte of the original string is either represented verbatim (as is the case with "z", "a", "g", or "j") or as a percent-encoded sequence of bytes (as was the case with "ż" which was originaly two bytes 197 and 188 and got converted to %C5 and %BC).

Now, we apply unescape:

```
unescape("za%C5%BC%C3%B3%C5%82%C4%87%20g%C4%99%C5%9Bl%C4%85%20ja%C5%BA%C5%84")
```

which gives

```
"zaÅ¼Ã³ÅÄ gÄÅlÄ jaÅºÅ"
```

If you are not native Polish speaker you might not notice, that this result is in fact way different from the original "zażółć gęślą jaźń". For starters, it has a different number of characters :)
For sure, you can tell, that this strange versions of big letter A do not belong to standard ascii set. In fact this "Å" has value 197. (which is exactly C5 in hexadecimal).

Now, if you are like me, you would ask yourself: wait a minute...if this is really a sequence of bytes with values 122, 97, 197, 188, and JS is really using UTF then why do I see this "Å¼" characters, and not the original "ż" ?

Well, the thing is (I belive) that this sequence 122, 97, 197, 188 (which we see when applying charCodeAt) is not a sequence of *bytes*, but a sequence of *codes*. The character "Å" has a code 197, but its actually two bytes long sequence: C3 85.

So, the trick works because unescape treats numbers occuring in percent-encoded string as codes, not as byte values - or, to be more specific: unescape knows nothing about multibyte characters, so when it decodes bytes one-by-one, handling values lower than 128 just great, but not-so-good when they are above 127 and multibyte -- unescape in such cases simply returns a multibyte character which happens to have a code equal to the requested byte value. This "bug" is actually useful feature.