# CRC32 in C# fails

Tags: c#, crc32

I was trying to implement my own CRC32 function in C#. I saw an elegant solution in JS here [JavaScript CRC32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638900/javascript-crc32)
So I came up with this:

```
internal static class Crc32
    {
        internal static long CalculateCrc32(string str)
        {
            long[] crcTable = Crc32.MakeCrcTable();
            long crc = 0 ^ (-1);

            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                char c = str[i];
                crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crcTable[(crc ^ c) & 0xFF];
            }

            return ~crc; //(crc ^ (-1)) >> 0;
        }

        internal static long[] MakeCrcTable()
        {
            long c;
            long[] crcTable = new long[256];
            for (int n = 0; n < 256; n++)
            {
                c = n;
                for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
                {
                    var res = c & 1;
                    c = (res == 1) ? (0xEDB88320 ^ (c >> 1)) : (c >> 1);
                }
                crcTable[n] = c;
            }

            return crcTable;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that my solution does not return the same result. `Console.WriteLine(Crc32.CalculateCrc32("l"));` results in 1762050814 while the JS function produces 2517025534. The JS result is also the correct one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you linked the right question? The one you linked is about a char code, not a JS CRC...

Comment: Can you not debug this to find the problem? Dump the CRC table and see if it matches. Dump the CRC after each calculation and see when they diverge, etc. We don't even have your reference implementation to compare against... Also google shows up many c# implementations that you could probably compare yours against to find the problem.

Comment: One thing that immediately makes me wonder is whether it is correct you are using Int64 to calcuate a CRC32? The name suggests 32 bit as does the implementation here: http://sanity-free.org/12/crc32_implementation_in_csharp.html

Comment: yes, it was the type. changed to uint and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using the wrong datatype. I'm not familiar with the CRC32 algorithm so I googled to find http://sanity-free.org/12/crc32_implementation_in_csharp.html as a reference implementation.

the first thing I noticed is that they are using `uint` instead of `long`. This makes sense as I'd assume the 32 in CRC32 means that it would return a 32 bit number. `long` is a 64 bit signed int.

If you change all the `long` for `uint` then we nearly get a working program. The only line that won't work is `c=n` because it can't implicitly convert an int (n) to a uint (c). However since we know n is always going to be a positive integer we can just change n to be of type `uint` as well.

This leaves me with:

```
internal static uint CalculateCrc32(string str)
{
    uint[] crcTable = Crc32.MakeCrcTable();
    uint crc = 0xffffffff;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = str[i];
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crcTable[(crc ^ c) & 0xFF];
    }

    return ~crc; //(crc ^ (-1)) >> 0;
}

internal static uint[] MakeCrcTable()
{
    uint c;
    uint[] crcTable = new uint[256];
    for (uint n = 0; n < 256; n++)
    {
        c = n;
        for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
        {
            var res = c & 1;
            c = (res == 1) ? (0xEDB88320 ^ (c >> 1)) : (c >> 1);
        }
        crcTable[n] = c;
    }

    return crcTable;
}
```

With this code `Console.WriteLine(Crc32.CalculateCrc32("l"));` displays `2517025534` as expected.

Comment: I got too busy debugging to think about types. thanks.

Comment: No problem. I really enjoy debugging challenges when they are nice and self contained like this. :)