# Sending iso-8859-1 via AJAX POST request?

Tags: javascript, ajax

first of all it is a userscript and I can't change the server-side encoding.

My problem is that when using encodeURIComponent() for encoding POST params (later sent via xhr.setRequestHeader), the characters are encoded in utf-8, but the server needs to receive iso-8859-1 data. Is there an alternative to encodeURIComponent() that would encode in iso-8859-1 ?

.

To make sure you understand, here is an exemple:

A classic form on the website send `é` like this: `yournewmessage:%E9`

Ajax via `xhr.send('yournewmessage='+encodeURIComponent('é'))` sends this: `yournewmessage:%E9%80%80`

The server needs the former. Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Not sure this makes much sense. URIs use UTF8 by specification, as defined in RFC2396.

Comment: @Polynomial Maybe it doesn't make much sense, but it is sometimes needed and web browsers know how to do it.

Comment: Only solution I can think of is to convert each *byte* (not char) in the string to a hex representation and upload that. There's a great answer about getting encoding-angostic byte arrays from strings in JS here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240408/reading-bytes-from-a-javascript-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I’ve since figured out this problem. What I did was searching for an equivalence between utf-8 and iso-8859-1, what I found was between utf-8 and cp1252 (Windows-1252) so there are two conversions, utf-8 to cp1252 and cp1252 to iso-8859-1 (these two having a lot of similarities)

http://pastebin.com/jTDqR2PQ

Ugly code, comments left in French, and unelegant solution, but I feel bad seeing this question unansered while I actually found a solution that works.