# Java String.getBytes("UTF8") JavaScript analog

Tags: java, javascript, string, utf-8, byte

[Bytes to string and backward](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/pack-and-unpack-bytes-to-strings)

Functions written there work properly that is `pack(unpack("string"))` yields to `"string"`. But I would like to have the same result as `"string".getBytes("UTF8")` gives in Java.

The question is how to make a function giving the same functionality as Java getBytes("UTF8") in JavaScript?

For Latin strings `unpack(str)` from the article mentioned above provides the same result as `getBytes("UTF8")` except it adds `0` for odd positions. But with non-Latin strings it works completely different as it seems to me. Is there a way to work with string data in JavaScript like Java does?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240408/reading-bytes-from-a-javascript-string) maybe?

Comment: Nope... `"中".getBytes("UTF8")` yields to `{-28, -72, -83}`, but the function from the answer to `[78, 45]`.

Comment: @Kremchik JavaScript uses UTF-16, hence the `0`s -- they're the upper half of each 16-bit code unit. That Hanzhi character requires 3-bytes when encoded according to UTF-8 scheme while only 2-bytes via UTF-16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this function ([gist](https://gist.github.com/3760795)):

```
function toUTF8Array(str) {
    var utf8 = [];
    for (var i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var charcode = str.charCodeAt(i);
        if (charcode < 0x80) utf8.push(charcode);
        else if (charcode < 0x800) {
            utf8.push(0xc0 | (charcode >> 6), 
                      0x80 | (charcode & 0x3f));
        }
        else if (charcode < 0xd800 || charcode >= 0xe000) {
            utf8.push(0xe0 | (charcode >> 12), 
                      0x80 | ((charcode>>6) & 0x3f), 
                      0x80 | (charcode & 0x3f));
        }
        else {
            // let's keep things simple and only handle chars up to U+FFFF...
            utf8.push(0xef, 0xbf, 0xbd); // U+FFFE "replacement character"
        }
    }
    return utf8;
}
```

Example of use:

```
>>> toUTF8Array("中€")
[228, 184, 173, 226, 130, 172]
```

If you want negative numbers for values over 127, like Java's byte-to-int conversion does, you have to tweak the constants and use

```
            utf8.push(0xffffffc0 | (charcode >> 6), 
                      0xffffff80 | (charcode & 0x3f));
```

and

```
            utf8.push(0xffffffe0 | (charcode >> 12), 
                      0xffffff80 | ((charcode>>6) & 0x3f), 
                      0xffffff80 | (charcode & 0x3f));
```

Comment: best answer, well done. also elegant code. I've made the method smaller and added a reverse method to `toUTF8Array`, the final touch is putting it all into `String.prototype` which made the usage **really** much more clear && simpler. check it out: [JavaScript-Bitwise-Shenanigans @GitHub](https://github.com/eladkarako/JavaScript-Bitwise-Shenanigans).

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to write a full-on UTF-8 encoder; there is a much easier JS idiom to convert a Unicode string into a string of bytes representing UTF-8 code units:

```
unescape(encodeURIComponent(str))
```

(This works because the odd encoding used by `escape`/`unescape` uses `%xx` hex sequences to represent ISO-8859-1 characters with that code, instead of UTF-8 as used by URI-component escaping. Similarly `decodeURIComponent(escape(bytes))` goes in the other direction.)

So if you want an Array out it would be:

```
function toUTF8Array(str) {
    var utf8= unescape(encodeURIComponent(str));
    var arr= new Array(utf8.length);
    for (var i= 0; i<utf8.length; i++)
        arr[i]= utf8.charCodeAt(i);
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`TextEncoder` is part of the [Encoding Living Standard](http://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/) and according to the [Encoding API](http://www.chromestatus.com/features/5714368087982080) entry from the Chromium Dashboard, it shipped in Firefox and will ship in Chrome 38.  There is also a [text-encoding](https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding) polyfill available for other browsers.

The JavaScript code sample below returns a `Uint8Array` filled with the values you expect.

```
(new TextEncoder()).encode("string") 
// [115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103]
```

A more interesting example that betters shows UTF-8 replaces the `in` in `string` with `îñ`:

```
(new TextEncoder()).encode("strîñg")
[115, 116, 114, 195, 174, 195, 177, 103]
```

Comment: This seems much better than the accepted bit-fiddling custom implementation that is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following function will deal with those above U+FFFF.

Because javascript text are in UTF-16, two "characters" are used in a string to represent a character above BMP, and charCodeAt returns the corresponding surrogate code. The fixedCharCodeAt handles this.

```
function encodeTextToUtf8(text) {
    var bin = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var v = fixedCharCodeAt(text, i);
        if (v === false) continue;
        encodeCharCodeToUtf8(v, bin);
    }
    return bin;
}

function encodeCharCodeToUtf8(codePt, bin) {
    if (codePt <= 0x7F) {
        bin.push(codePt);
    } else if (codePt <= 0x7FF) {
        bin.push(192 | (codePt >> 6), 128 | (codePt & 63));
    } else if (codePt <= 0xFFFF) {
        bin.push(224 | (codePt >> 12),
            128 | ((codePt >> 6) & 63),
            128 | (codePt & 63));
    } else if (codePt <= 0x1FFFFF) {
        bin.push(240 | (codePt >> 18),
            128 | ((codePt >> 12) & 63), 
            128 | ((codePt >> 6) & 63),
            128 | (codePt & 63));
    }
}

function fixedCharCodeAt (str, idx) {  
    // ex. fixedCharCodeAt ('\uD800\uDC00', 0); // 65536  
    // ex. fixedCharCodeAt ('\uD800\uDC00', 1); // 65536  
    idx = idx || 0;  
    var code = str.charCodeAt(idx);  
    var hi, low;  
    if (0xD800 <= code && code <= 0xDBFF) { // High surrogate (could change last hex to 0xDB7F to treat high private surrogates as single characters)  
        hi = code;  
        low = str.charCodeAt(idx+1);  
        if (isNaN(low)) {  
            throw(encoding_error.invalid_surrogate_pair.replace('%pos%', idx));
        }  
        return ((hi - 0xD800) * 0x400) + (low - 0xDC00) + 0x10000;  
    }  
    if (0xDC00 <= code && code <= 0xDFFF) { // Low surrogate  
        // We return false to allow loops to skip this iteration since should have already handled high surrogate above in the previous iteration  
        return false;  
        /*hi = str.charCodeAt(idx-1); 
          low = code; 
          return ((hi - 0xD800) * 0x400) + (low - 0xDC00) + 0x10000;*/  
    }  
    return code;  
}
```