# MD5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value)) into javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, unicode, md5, cryptojs

I need to translate the line below from vb.net to javascript

```
MD5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value))
```

Im trying to use CryptoJS but I get diffrent results as I need to pass a string into that but a byte array into the MD5 function in VB.net

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java String.getBytes("UTF8") JavaScript analog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518830/java-string-getbytesutf8-javascript-analog)

Answer (score 0):

`Encoding.Unicode` is a (misleading) name used by Windows for the UTF-16LE encoding.

However the CryptoJS functions, when given a string, encode it to bytes using the (more common) UTF-8, not UTF-16LE:

> The hash algorithms accept either strings or instances of CryptoJS.lib.WordArray. A WordArray object represents an array of 32-bit words. When you pass a string, it's automatically converted to a WordArray encoded as UTF-8.

So you will need to create a WordArray from the string yourself before passing it in to MD5. With a new enough CryptoJS there's a function to do that for you:

```
CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Utf16LE.parse(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

IN C#:

```
var data = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(password));
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) {
    stringBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
}
return stringBuilder.ToString();
```

In Node.js

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

crypto.createHash('md5').update(value).digest('hex');
```