# C# SHA256 ComputeHash with salt to get the same result with Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, encoding, hash, salt

I have a C# function as below:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class Program
{
    public static int SaltValueSize = 4;
    
    public static string HashPassword(string clearData, string saltValue, HashAlgorithm hash)
    {
        var encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        var binarySaltValue = new byte[SaltValueSize];

        binarySaltValue[0] = byte.Parse(saltValue.Substring(0, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
        binarySaltValue[1] = byte.Parse(saltValue.Substring(2, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
        binarySaltValue[2] = byte.Parse(saltValue.Substring(4, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
        binarySaltValue[3] = byte.Parse(saltValue.Substring(6, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);

        var valueToHash = new byte[SaltValueSize + encoding.GetByteCount(clearData)];
        var binaryPassword = encoding.GetBytes(clearData);

        binarySaltValue.CopyTo(valueToHash, 0);
        binaryPassword.CopyTo(valueToHash, SaltValueSize);

        // The result of valueToHash is
        // 1861251472347701210800970115011501190111011401000640490500510520530330


        var hashValue = hash.ComputeHash(valueToHash);
        var hashedPassword = saltValue;

        return BitConverter.ToString(hashValue);
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        var data = HashPassword("MyPassword@12345!", "BA7D93EA", SHA256.Create());
        Console.WriteLine("HashedPassword {0}", data);
    }
}
```

I've seen similar questions in Stackoverflow like this:

[C# SHA256 ComputeHash result different with CryptoJS SHA256 function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35984198/c-sharp-sha256-computehash-result-different-with-cryptojs-sha256-function)

[MD5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value)) into javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262472/md5-computehashencoding-unicode-getbytesvalue-into-javascript)

But this answer can't help me because they're not using salt, and I can't find a way to apply this in JavaScript

I've almost rewritten this function in JavaScript but I'm stuck with the last step with function `ComputeHash`

```
const hashPassword = (password, salt) => {
  const binarySaltValue = [];

  binarySaltValue[0] = parseInt(salt.substring(0, 2), 16);
  binarySaltValue[1] = parseInt(salt.substring(2, 4), 16);
  binarySaltValue[2] = parseInt(salt.substring(4, 6), 16);
  binarySaltValue[3] = parseInt(salt.substring(6, 8), 16);

  const binaryPassword = [];

  Buffer.from(password)
    .toJSON()
    .data.forEach((v) => {
      binaryPassword.push(v);
      binaryPassword.push(0);
    });

  const valueToHash = [...binarySaltValue, ...binaryPassword].join('');

  // The result of valueToHash is the same as in C# example
  // 1861251472347701210800970115011501190111011401000640490500510520530330

  return valueToHash;
};

console.log(hashPassword('MyPassword@12345!', 'BA7D93EA'));
```

As you can see I've got the same array of bytes, but I'm missing the last piece with the `ComputeHash` function, could someone please help me with this

Comment: Do i undestand it right that your question essentially boils down to "_How to calculate SHA-256 from some byte buffer in JavaScript_"? (As a side note: Your Javascript code so far and its valueToHash value will _only_ be equal to the C# valueToHash value when the password _exclusively_ contains characters with ordinal values smaller than 255. Use a non-ASCII character with an ordinal value larger than 255 in your password, and your JS valueToHash value will be different from the C# valueToHash value.)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace yes, and if it's only hashing the password itself, I won't have any problem with that, but the original logic in the C# example is that Salt value is prepended before the password and I'm having an issue with that, in the similar thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/36026310/18223019 there is an answer that perfectly suits me, except one thing, that there only password is hashing and I don't know how to properly prepend the salt to it

Comment: Color me utterly confused. Nothing in your question suggests you have problem with your C# code. Now, do you have problems with the C# code, the JS code, or both? If you have problems with the C# code, i strongly suggest you deal with it separatly from the problems you have with your JS code. (I.e., ask a new question only about either JS or C# code. Then, if you got answer and a working solution for that, you may follow up with another question about your problems with the other language code, if there would still be problems with that.)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace no, I don't have problems with C# code, my goal is to port this code in JavaScript to be able to generate the same password but on a NodeJS platform

Comment: Ah, alright, then i misinterpreted your previous comment. My apologies...